# PHP's Xpath to parse for a url in a form's action attribute

Tags: php, xpath

Considering this HTML code:

```
<div id="something_unique">
 <form action="http://the_needed_link">
 </form>
</div>
```

How do we get the needed link assuming that there is a lot of form tags on the page but we do only need the one that is in a div that has a unique id?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should do it:

```
//div[@id="something_unique"]/form/@action
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I was off by one char; a missing slash between the element and the attribute. Here's a full example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'utf-8' );
$doc->loadXML(
    '<root>
    <div id="something_unique">
        <form action="http://the_needed_link">
        </form>
    </div>
    </root>
    '
);

$xpath = new DomXPath( $doc );
$result = $xpath->query( '//div[@id="something_unique"]/form/@action' );

var_dump( $result->item( 0 )->nodeValue );
```

Comment: @Tomalak, you are right! Thanks. I just tested it myself, because I wasn't sure. I'll update my answer with a full example.